# Проблема с установкой скомпилированного apk-файла

Tags: android

Устанавливаю на телефон с версией 4.4.2 свое приложение - выводит что невозможно установить, пробовал установить на тел. с версией 5.1 - установилось, в чем проблема может быть, если `minSdk`=19?
`minSdkVersion` 19
`targetSdkVersion` 23

Answer (score 1):

`targetSdkVersion` = максимальный уровень поддерживаемой апи

`minSdkVersion` = минимальный поддерживаемый уровень апи

Укажите `minSdkVersion` 16 для поддержки ОС начиная с  Jelly bean и выше

Вообще, как минимум скиньте сюда ошибку из студии.